# animation start when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bar chart that animates with CSS3 and the animation currently activates as the page loads.

The problem I have is that the given bar chart is placed off screen due to lots of content before it so by the time a user scrolls down to it, the animation has already finished.

I was looking for ways either through CSS3 or jQuery to only activate the CSS3 animation on the bar chart when the viewer sees the chart.

```css
.animation {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

table {
    width: 100%;

}

.tr-box table,
.tr-box tr,
.tr-box td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tr-box tr td:first-child {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

.tr-box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tr-box tr td {
    padding: 10px;
}




.a-box-animation {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: box;
    animation-name: box;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


@keyframes box {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
        background-color: blue;

    }
    100% {
        background-color: blue
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="popularity">

        <div class="animation ">

            <h2>Most popular books</h2>
            <div class='tr-box'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>The Snowman</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="a-box-animation">

                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
          </div>

    </section>
```

=======

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event handler to the scroll event, and to check if the element is in the viewport when scrolling. If yes, then add an extra class to it to enable its animation.

```
function isElementInViewport (el) {

    //special bonus for those using jQuery
    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }

    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (isElementInViewport($('.box'))) {
        $('.box').addClass('animate')
    }
})
```

You'll want to extract the general css style into a class like `box`, and put styles about animation into class `animate`.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use scroll event. When element come in current viewpoint - script add a class for element

```
addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  var current_pos = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.body.scrollTop;
  if (current_pos - $('#popularity').offset().top < $(window).height() * 0.2) {
    $('#animation-box').addClass('a-box-animation');
  }
});
```

and i remove class with animation and add id for it

```
<div id="animation-box"></div>
```